# Gson parsing a Json to a Realm object with SerializedName fields

Tags: java, android, json, gson, realm

I'm parsing a json string to a Realm object, but the json has the key "id", So I'm using a serializedName to bypass it.

Here is my Json (jsonString in the following example)

```
{
    "id": "someuuidString",
    ...
    (some more irrelevant fields)
}
```

Here is my object decleration

```
public class MyObject extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String MyObjectId;
    ...
    (some more irrelevant fields, constructors, getters and setters)
}
```

And later in the code i try the following

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyObject.class);
```

So instead of parsing correctly, it crashes with the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.example.objects.MyObject declares multiple JSON fields named id
```

So, what did I miss?

Comment: It seems you need to ignore json serializing of your primaryKey field. When seriliazer tries to parse json, it is confused as it sees two fields named id.

Comment: You're sending two fields named `id`, if you want to control which fields you expose, then you must enable `@Expose` on your Gson instance and mark the field you want to send with `@Expose`

Comment: thanks @EpicPandaForce, that was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because @SerializedName treats MyObjectId as "id", so you have 2 fields called id.

Change your object to

```
public class MyObject extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long databaseId; 

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String MyObjectId;
    ...
    (some more irrelevant fields, constructors, getters and setters)
}
```

Generally maybe better is to remove this databaseId and set @PrimaryKey on MyObjectId. It depends on your needs

Comment: Yes, this is a good answer to my problem, I didn't declare though  in my question I needed my primary key to have the name "id". so the commend from EpicPandaForce helped me with the Gson Expose functionality. I'll mark this as the correct answer since it was the first answer to solve the written question.

Answer (score 0):

You got error because id conflicts with your primary key and JSON key, Change your primary key name,

Try as below,

```
public class MyObject extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long primaryId;

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String MyObjectId;
    ...
    (some more irrelevant fields, constructors, getters and setters)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you are correct but mac229 was earlier so I marked his solution as the answer.